# Aggregate Data Frame Containing Strings and Numbers

Tags: r, string, aggregate

I am attempting to aggregate or group a data frame base on a common field. Beyond wanting to sum some demographic numbers with the aggregation, I am also trying to aggregate string fields. Within some of the string fields (ie, County, State, Countycode, etc) they are always the same amongst those with the same common field, but some of the string fields (ie, Congressional district, Senate House, et) are unique amongst those with the same common field.

The objective is to combine fields with the same value in the `COMMON_FIELD`. For the string fields that are unique within their common field group, I need R to select the values from one of the common field groups. It doesn't matter from which row it acquires the values as long as it is a row that shares the common field value.

Code Sample

```
IDENTIFICATION | COUNTY | TOTAL_POPULATION | YOUTH_POPULATION | COMMON_FIELD
Oakland-013  |  Alameda   |   3000        |        1000      |      A1-3
Oakland-012  |  Alameda   |   5000        |        2000       |     A1-3
```

Desired Results:

```
IDENTIFICATION | COUNTY | TOTAL_POPULATION | YOUTH_POPULATION | COMMON_FIELD
Oakland-013  |  Alameda   |   8000       |         3000      |      A1-3
```

Thus, although the identification field will be unique amongst groups with the same common field, I would like R to pick one from the groups in the common field and it doesn't matter which it picks.

Comment: The IDENTIFICATION looks like different.  You coul do, `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(COUNTY, COMMON_FIELD) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)), IDENTIFICATION = first(IDENTIFICATION))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can do multiple aggregates on blocks of columns by group.  The 'IDENTIFICATION' values are showed to be different, based on the expected, we can select the `first` element of that column for each group

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.0.0
df1 %>% 
   group_by(COUNTY, COMMON_FIELD) %>% 
   # // use across for more than one column
   # // checks the type of columns i.e. numeric to select and return the sum
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
               IDENTIFICATION = first(IDENTIFICATION))
```

---

The OP's original dataset code can be changed to

```
GAcatalistDupes %>% 
   group_by(FIPS, CAT_JOIN) %>%
   # // summarise numeric columns
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE),
             # // get the first value for specified columns
             across(c(geography, CONG, SS, SH, Field23, FIPS), first))
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I added a few more fields and it seems to have an error. 


GAcatalistDupes %>% group_by(FIPS, CAT_JOIN) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) 
                                          geography = first(geography) & 
                                          CONG = first(CONG) & 
                                          SS = first(SS) &
                                          SH = first(SH) &
                                          Field23 = first(Field23) &
                                          Field24 = first(FIPS))

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril your code with `&` won't work.  I didn't show that part in my code.  You may need `GAcatalistDupes %>% group_by(FIPS, CAT_JOIN) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)), geography = first(geography), CONG = first(CONG) , SS = first(SS) , SH = first(SH), Field23 = first(Field23), Field24 = first(FIPS))`

Comment: I think it just has to do with my bad formatting. The error is: 
We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril the issue is that you had `&` instead of `,` I updated the previous comment with the correct syntax

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril I updated with a more compact option for your code

Comment: Yes, thank you. With the commas, R is giving me an error that says unexpected tokens ',' and ')'.

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril can you copy/paste the code in my post and test it

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril you are right.  Previously, there was a mismatch in the `)`

Comment: It gives me this:

Error: unexpected ',' in "GAcatalistDupes %>% group_by(FIPS, CAT_JOIN) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)),"

Comment: @KimberlyBecerrili I changed that code (a typo from my side - sorry), please use the new updated one because the`),` should be correct and not `)),`

Comment: Awesome! It no longer has an error but the dimensions were not reduced from before the grouping. I'll do a bit more digging. Thanks again for your help @akrun :)

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril that is a strange case because if you do `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarise(across(c(mpg, disp), sum), across(c(vs, carb), first))` I get 8 rows and 6 columns.

Comment: @KimberlyBecerril If you want to update the original object, you need `GAcatalistDupes <- GAcatalistDupes %>% 
   group_by(FIPS, CAT_JOIN) %>%
   # // summarise numeric columns
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE),
             # // get the first value for specified columns
             across(c(geography, CONG, SS, SH, Field23, FIPS), first))`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a `data.table` solution which applies the `sum()` function if a column is numeric and picks the first value if the column is non-numeric:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if (is.numeric(x)) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) else first(x)), 
           by = COMMON_FIELD]
```

> ```
>    COMMON_FIELD IDENTIFICATION  COUNTY TOTAL_POPULATION YOUTH_POPULATION
> 1:         A1-3    Oakland-013 Alameda             8000             3000
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("IDENTIFICATION | COUNTY | TOTAL_POPULATION | YOUTH_POPULATION | COMMON_FIELD
Oakland-013  |  Alameda   |   3000        |        1000      |      A1-3
Oakland-012  |  Alameda   |   5000        |        2000       |     A1-3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
  . ~ COMMON_FIELD,
  df,
  function(x) {
    ifelse(any(is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x)))),
      sample(x, 1),
      sum(as.numeric(x))
    )
  }
)
```

which gives

```
  COMMON_FIELD IDENTIFICATION  COUNTY TOTAL_POPULATION YOUTH_POPULATION
1         A1-3    Oakland-012 Alameda             8000             3000
```